# SP fast deploy error "File not found"

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, deployment, react

I've been getting this error but the bundle file is already present. Can anyone help me out

```
Fast deploying to SP App C:\Users\xanderCage\Desktop\xanderCage.Apps.SharePoint-Dev1.0_react\OnboardingApp\Scripts\dist\adminBundle.js ...
Error deploying to SP App C:\Users\xanderCage\Desktop\xanderCage.Apps.SharePoint-Dev1.0_react\OnboardingApp\Scripts\dist\adminBundle.js Error: File Not Found.
Fast deploying to SP App C:\Users\xanderCage\Desktop\xanderCage.Apps.SharePoint-Dev1.0_react\OnboardingApp\Scripts\dist\adminBundle.min.js ...
Error deploying to SP App C:\Users\xanderCage\Desktop\xanderCage.Apps.SharePoint-Dev1.0_react\OnboardingApp\Scripts\dist\adminBundle.min.js Error: File Not Found.
Fast deploying to SP App C:\Users\xanderCage\Desktop\xanderCage.Apps.SharePoint-Dev1.0_react\OnboardingApp\Scripts\dist\adminBundle.min.js ...
Error deploying to SP App C:\Users\xanderCage\Desktop\xanderCage.Apps.SharePoint-Dev1.0_react\OnboardingApp\Scripts\dist\adminBundle.min.js Error: File Not Found.
```

Comment: I am not familiar with SPFastDeploy but it seems to be for deploying add-ins, not SPFx solutions..? Are you able to deploy your bundle manually?

Comment: Hello Rune, 
Firstly, thanks for your response. Now coming to your question, yes i am able to deploy it to app catalog and i can even find the file in the site and i checked it while debugging it.

Comment: So then I guess this question is about a third party tool - I don't think you'll find much help on that here. From what I can see this isn't something you would even use with SPFx...

Comment: We use it to replace the minified js files instead of deploying the whole add in again. But I hope some one responds asap